# How to capture HTML <select> element's values in server side using expressJS?

Tags: html, express

This is a drop-down filtering box I created in `HTML`:

```
<select name="pets" id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
```

Suppose I select one pet from above, in the server side using expressjs, how should I write to capture the value of the pet I selected?
I'm guessing a 'get' route and `req.query` are needed, yet I'm not sure how?

```
app.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    //some codes here
}
```

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

[`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) used to parse URL query string, for you to be able to get the form input/select values, you should use for your GET request handler [`req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params), check the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) on how to handle the request object:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.params.pets); // <--- this will console.log the HTML form elements values.
}
```